# How to instance many parameters for Factory class with Kodein

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, dependency-injection, kodein

I'm using `Kodein` as injecting dependency for my `kotlin` project. So I have a factory of my ViewModel like below

```
class ReadViewModelFactory(private val readRepository: ReadRepositoryImpl, private val activity: ReadActivity) : ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory() {

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {

        val guid = activity.intent.getIntExtra(Constants.EXTRA_GUID, 0)
        val pubDate = activity.intent.getStringExtra(Constants.EXTRA_DATE)
        val title = activity.intent.getStringExtra(Constants.EXTRA_TITLE)
        val headImage = activity.intent.getStringExtra(Constants.EXTRA_IMAGE_URL)
        val kanal = activity.intent.getStringExtra(Constants.EXTRA_KANAL_READ)
        val intentRead = IntentRead(guid, pubDate, title, headImage, kanal)
        return ReadViewModel(readRepository, intentRead) as T
    }
}
```

Then, in my Application class, I've created:

```
class App : MultiDexApplication(), KodeinAware{

    override val kodein = Kodein.lazy {
        import(androidXModule(this@App))

        bind() from singleton { NetworkConnectionInterceptor(instance()) }
        bind() from singleton { ApiService(instance()) }
        bind() from provider { ReadViewModelFactory(instance(),instance())}

    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have two params for my `ReadViewModelFactory`. But when I run my application crash occurred in `ReadActivity`. What console log said

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{id.my.app/id.my.app.ui.read.ReadActivity}:
>   org.kodein.di.Kodein$NotFoundException: No binding found for
>   bind() with ?().? { ? }
>       Registered in this Kodein container:

My `ReadActivity` looks like below:

```
class ReadActivity : AppCompatActivity(), KodeinAware{

  override val kodein by kodein()

    private val factory : ReadViewModelFactory by instance()

 .......

}
```

fullstack trace

> 08-21 11:23:54.807 27186-27186/id.my.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: id.my.app, PID: 27186
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{id.my.app/id.grid.app.ui.read.ReadActivity}:
>   org.kodein.di.Kodein$NotFoundException: No binding found for
>   bind() with ?().? { ? }
>       Registered in this Kodein container:
>               bind() with provider { ReadViewModelFactory }
>               bind() with singleton { HomeFragmentRepositoryImpl }
>               bind() with provider { HomeFragmentViewModelFactory }
>               bind() with provider { HomeViewModelFactory }
>               bind() with singleton { NetworkConnectionInterceptor }
>               bind() with singleton { HomeRepositoryImpl }
>               bind() with singleton { ReadRepositoryImpl }
>               bind() with singleton { ApiService }
>               module ⁣androidModule {
>                   bind(tag = "externalCache") with contexted().provider { File }
>                   bind() with contexted().provider { MediaProjectionManager }
>                   bind() with contexted().provider { JobScheduler }
>                   bind(tag = "files") with contexted().provider { File }
>                   bind(tag = "cache") with contexted().provider { File }
>                   bind() with contexted().provider { TvInputManager }
>                   bind() with contexted().provider { PrintManager }
>                   bind(tag = "packageCodePath") with contexted().provider { String }
>                   bind() with contexted().provider { AccountManager }
>                   bind() with contexted().provider { UiModeManager }
>                   bind() with contexted().provider { ApplicationInfo }
>                   bind() with contexted().provider { Looper }
>                   bind() with contexted().provider { WindowManager }
>                   bind() with contexted().provider { UsageStatsManager }
>                   bind() with contexted().provider { InputMethodManager }
>                   bind() with contexted().provider { MediaRouter }
>                   bind() with contexted().provider { ActivityManager }
>                   bind() with contexted().provider { RestrictionsManager }
>                   bind() with contexted().provider { SensorManager }
>                   bind() with contexted().provider { LauncherApps }
>                   bind() with contexted().provider { Resources.Theme }
>                   bind() with contexted().provider { DropBoxManager }
>                   bind() with contexted().provider { AccessibilityManager }
>                   bind() with contexted().provider { AssetManager }
>                   bind() with contexted().provider { CarrierConfigManager }
>                   bind() with contexted().provider { AudioManager }
>                   bind() with contexted().provider { MidiManager }
>                   bind() with contexted().provider { MediaSessionManager }
>                   bind() with contexted().provider { InputManager }
>                   bind() with contexted().provider { WallpaperManager }
>                   bind() with contexted().provider { PackageManager }
>                   bind() with contexted().provider { DownloadManager }
>                   bind() with contexted().provider { BatteryManager }
>                   bind() with contexted().provider { SharedPreferences }
>                   bind

Comment: This looks like a proguard / dexguard issue.
Is minyfying enabled in your project ?

Comment: minifyEnabled false in my gradle

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: i have updated my question with full stacktrace

Comment: i think i know what cause this. It's because i use Activity as parameters of ReadViewModelFactory. In practically, most of tutorial use context, but i need activity

Comment: The `No binding found for
> bind<ReadActivity>() with ?<ReadActivity>().? { ? }` tells me that you are trying to retrieve the activity itself from kodein, as if you were doing `val activity: ReadActivity by instance()`. Can you check all your retrievals ?

Comment: i want to get intent value from activity, which is not provide with context

Comment: can you help me to solve my issue? do you have any suggestion related to obtain intent for ViewModelFactory parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class `ReadViewModelFactory` has a `ReadActivity` constructor parameter, which is not bound in Kodein.

There are 2 ways you can solve this:

**1. Use context**

Because you are retrieving directly in `ReadActivity`, the activity is the context, so you can bind with context:

```
bind() from contexted<ReadActivity>.provider { ReadViewModelFactory(instance(), context)}
```

Then, in `ReadActivity`, you can retrieve like this:

```
private val factory : ReadViewModelFactory by instance()
```

However, in another class, you'd have to specify the context explicitely:

```
private val factory : ReadViewModelFactory by on(activity).instance()
```

**2. Use factory**

You can pass the activity as a parameter, which has the advantage of having the same retrieval syntax everywhere:

```
bind() from factory { activity: ReadActivity -> ReadViewModelFactory(instance(), activity)}
```

Then, in retrieval:

```
private val factory : ReadViewModelFactory by instance(arg = activity)
```

Comment: In my case, I had to use newInstance instead of instance. example: newInstance(arg = someArg)